# Best practice python init check

Tags: python, class, init

What would be the best way to initialize attributes and check provided parameters when initializing a python class? Suppose that there are multiple parameters in the `__init__()` and some of them have to comply to certain rules. There is also the need to have setters and getters for some of them. I can think of the option from below. How does it look to you? Are there any better options?

Option: Initialize attributes `None` and call the setter, where the check is performed.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, p1=None, ..., pn=None):
        self._p1 = None
        ...
        self._pn = None

        if p1 is not None:
            self.p1 = p1
        ...
        if pn is not None:
            self.pn = pn

    @p1.setter
    def p1(self, p1):
        # If p1 is int we can just take it
        if isinstance(p1, int):
            self._p1 = p1
        # If p1 is str we have to obtain it differently
        elif isinstance(p1, str):
            self._p1 = self._gen_some_p_from_str(p1)
        else:
            raise Exception('Incorrect p1 type provided.')
    ...
    @pn.setter
    def pn(self, pn):
        # If pn instance of SomeOtherClass it should be also great
        if isinstance(pn, SomeOtherClass):
            if pn.great():
                self._pn = pn
            else:
                raise exception('pn not great')
        # pn can be also str, and then we should get it
        elif isinstance(pn, str):
             self._pn = self._get_some_other_p_from_str(pn)
        else:
            raise Exception('Incorrect pn type provided.')
```

Comment: Get rid of the checks. Write proper documentation/docstrings. From here it's garbage in -> garbage out.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to run the validation on each assign, property is your way.

Keep in mind that this might have a performance issue when you will have many assignments(like in a loop).

Your issue can be solved by validate the input only on the initiation of the class, you better have a `clean` or `validate` method on your class, then call it in the end of the `__init__` func.

Using this method you can call your `clean` method whenever you need, and omit the call where performance are more important than the validation(This is how [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) works).

In your case, your are trying to do overloading/dispatching, take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you detail it a bit? I need different validation functions for different arguments and I was thinking if it is possible to remove the if in the `__init__()` and keep the `_*` at the same time.

Comment: But then every time you will call `pq=something` your validation will apply, this might be costly when running this on multiple attributes, multiple times(like in a for loop). your can define a `clean` method so you can control when the validation occurs - you if this fits for your situation better then me,